# Why is jQuery firing mouseover on an element as the mouse leaves?

Tags: jquery, hover

Example page: http://workshop.grdev.co.nz/mousetime

There are five divs which should respond to mouseover.

A switch (hoverDemo.doAnim) is set to false when the expand animation starts. This is intended to prevent the animation firing repeatedly when the mouse is placed so that the animation alternates between expanding two adjacent divs. Entertaining, but not what we want.

```
hoverDemo = {

  doAnim: true,
  animDelay: 250,
  marginBottom: 20,
  marginTop: 50, // provides space for h2
  heightContracted: 100,

  init: function() {
    $('.outer .inner').each( hoverDemo.contractDiv );
    $('.outer .inner').mouseover( hoverDemo.expandDiv );    
  },

  expandDiv: function() {
    $('#debug-last').html(this.id);   
    if ( hoverDemo.doAnim ) {
      hoverDemo.doAnim = false ;
      $('#debug-ignore').html('IGNORING MOUSE');
      $('.outer .inner').removeClass('expanded');
      $(this).addClass('expanded');
      var those = $('.outer .inner').not('.expanded');
      $(this).animate( { height: $(this).find('p').height()+hoverDemo.marginBottom+hoverDemo.marginTop }, hoverDemo.animDelay, function() {
        hoverDemo.doAnim = true ;
        $('#debug-ignore').html('');
        those.each( hoverDemo.contractDiv );
      } );
    }
  },

  contractDiv: function() {
    $(this).animate( { height: hoverDemo.heightContracted }, hoverDemo.animDelay );
  }
} ;
$(document).ready(hoverDemo.init);
```

When the mouse moves from Lorem to Praesent, the JS function hoverDemo.expandDiv is fired as the mouse *leaves* the Lorem div.inner ... and I'm unsure why this is happening.

You can observe this by moving the mouse into Lorem, waiting until the IGNORING MOUSE message goes away, then slowly moving it down out of the expanded Lorem div.

If you move the mouse to the sides, it doesn't fire the same function - only when moving down.

If you move your mouse down from one div to another, frequently the second div won't be expanded. Dependent on mouse speed and animation timing, you might see every other div get expanded, and so forth.

Questions:

What about this code causes the mouseover event to fire when the mouse is just leaving the expanded div, and why it only happens as the mouse leaves via the bottom edge?

What's the best way to make the currently hovered block expand, while preventing the bounce effects?

Demo uses jQuery 1.2.6, as this is the version of jQuery which is currently in use on the site.

Behaviour observed in OSX Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend updating jQuery, to at least version 1.4.2.

Comment: I agree. I'm not attached to jQuery 1.2.6 except that it's what ships with Drupal 6.x (which the site is built in) and what already works with various other plugins on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution (or, a good solution) is to use the hoverIntent plugin.

Adding this pretty much made it behave as I hoped it would. It doesn't answer my question about why, but it does fix the problem :)

Plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Updated code: http://workshop.grdev.co.nz/mouseintent

```
hoverDemo = {

  doAnim: true,
  animDelay: 250,
  marginBottom: 20,
  marginTop: 50, // provides space for h2
  heightContracted: 100,

  init: function() {
    $('.outer .inner').each( hoverDemo.contractDiv );
    $('.outer .inner').hoverIntent( hoverDemo.expandDiv, hoverDemo.contractDiv );    
  },

  expandDiv: function() {
   $(this).animate( { height: $(this).find('p').height()+hoverDemo.marginBottom+hoverDemo.marginTop }, hoverDemo.animDelay );
  },

  contractDiv: function() {
    $(this).animate( { height: hoverDemo.heightContracted }, hoverDemo.animDelay );
  }
} ;
$(document).ready(hoverDemo.init);
```

Comment: I've accepted this solution to close the question, but I'm still really intrigued why this behaviour occurs. If you've got a better answer, I'd be happy to hear it!